# Why don't horizontalCenter and verticalCenter work in Spark (Flex 4)?

Tags: apache-flex, flex-spark

Here's code that splits the screen into two columns, left and right.  Then it puts a box in each column and attempts to center them.  The horizontalCenter and verticalCenter properties are ignored:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<s:Application xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" 
               xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark" 
               xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx"
               backgroundColor="blue">
    <fx:Declarations>
        <!-- Place non-visual elements (e.g., services, value objects) here -->
    </fx:Declarations>
    <s:SkinnableContainer id="mainContentArea"
             top="100" bottom="100"
             backgroundColor="red">
        <s:layout>
            <s:ConstraintLayout>
                <s:constraintColumns>
                    <s:ConstraintColumn id="col1" width="{width/2}" />
                    <s:ConstraintColumn id="col2" width="{width/2}" />              
                </s:constraintColumns>                  
            </s:ConstraintLayout>
        </s:layout>
        <s:BorderContainer id="greenContainer"
                           backgroundColor="green"
                           width="400" height="300"
                           horizontalCenter="col1:0"
                           verticalCenter="0">
        </s:BorderContainer>    
        <s:BorderContainer id="yellowContainer"
                           backgroundColor="yellow"
                           width="200" height="150"
                           horizontalCenter="col2:0"
                           verticalCenter="0">
        </s:BorderContainer>        
    </s:SkinnableContainer>
</s:Application>
```

Answer (score 1):

From [the documentation](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/spark/layouts/ConstraintLayout.html):

> Per-element supported constraints are `left`, `right`, `top`, `bottom`,
>   `baseline`, `percentWidth`, and `percentHeight`. Element's minimum and
>   maximum sizes will always be respected.

So `horizontalCenter` and `verticalCenter` are not in the list of supported constraints.

I recommend you to use the following code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<s:Application xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" 
    xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark" 
    xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx"
    backgroundColor="blue">
    <fx:Declarations>
        <!-- Place non-visual elements (e.g., services, value objects) here -->
    </fx:Declarations>
    <s:SkinnableContainer id="mainContentArea"
        top="100" bottom="100"
        backgroundColor="red" left="0" right="0">
        <s:layout>
            <s:ConstraintLayout>
                <s:constraintColumns>
                    <s:ConstraintColumn id="col1" width="50%" />
                    <s:ConstraintColumn id="col2" width="50%" />              
                </s:constraintColumns>                  
            </s:ConstraintLayout>
        </s:layout>
        <s:Group left="col1:0" right="col1:0" top="0" bottom="0">
            <s:BorderContainer id="greenContainer"
                backgroundColor="green"
                width="400" height="300"
                horizontalCenter="0"
                verticalCenter="0">
            </s:BorderContainer>    
        </s:Group>
        <s:Group left="col2:0" right="col2:0" top="0" bottom="0">
            <s:BorderContainer id="yellowContainer"
                backgroundColor="yellow"
                width="200" height="150"
                horizontalCenter="0"
                verticalCenter="0">
            </s:BorderContainer>        
        </s:Group>
    </s:SkinnableContainer>
</s:Application>
```

Comment: So how does one achieve the same functionality in Spark?  Why was this changed?  The same code in MX works (using Canvas).

Comment: I suppose you should place a `Group` with `left=right=top=bottom="0"` and the place your control inside it with `verticalCenter` and `horizontalCenter`. And I haven't answer on a second part of the question because I haven't any thoughts about Adobe's motives.

Comment: Thanks for your attention on this.  Not sure if I get your drift.  Can you post edited code that works? Unfortunately can't place controls in different groups.  Have to be in the same container as I'm swapping them, resizing them, transitioning them via different states.  The two boxes have to be centered via ConstraintColumns.  Again, this works in MX. I'm trying to post the MX code.

Comment: Again, thank you for the attention.  I had gone down that path.  Unfortunately, as I say, the components must exist within the same group.  Different groups won't work because of the need to swap the boxes.  Picture a "reverse" button upper right that when clicked reverses the position of the boxes.  When the boxes reverse, they smoothly transition to their new reversed positions.  Those transitions won't work if the components are in different groups.  They have to be horizontally centered on a ColumnConstraint, not a Group container.  I'm stumped.  Again, I have this working in MX.

Comment: Why not to move groups with transitions? I understand your point about MX. But this is Sparta, sorry, Spark. It is an other components set with other features.

Comment: I understand Spark is a different realm.  We have a very excellent and complex MX app that we're transitioning to Spark so as to take advantage of the new skinning model and facilitate parallel browser and mobile skins.  The app behaves as described with various states and smooth transitions from state to state.  I can't change the behavior.  The boxes must move, resize, appear, disappear, and transition smoothly as such.  When the boxes are in different groups the transitions don't work - probably because the boxes have to be physically removed from one container and added to another.

Comment: I just heard back from Adobe on this.  They said, "we didn't have enough time to implement horizontal/verticalCenter in the last release (hopefully coming in the next!).".  I asked if they meant for all Spark containers or what.  They responded, "Yes, basically, they are not implemented in ConstraintLayout. ConstraintLayout handles all of the ConstraintColumns/ConstraintRows layout logic."  So that leaves me stuck until the next release unless I can find a workaround.

Comment: Good luck with waiting from Adobe :)